# How to only keep nodes in networkx-graph with 2+ outgoing edges or 0 outgoing edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I have Directed Graph in networkx. I want to only keep those nodes which have two or more than two outgoing edges or no outgoing edge at all. How do I do this?

or

How do I removes nodes which have exactly one outgoing edge in a networkx graph.

Comment: If you start with a graph, find the nodes which have one outgoing edge, and then remove those, you can create a new graph which still has a node with one outgoing edge (say it had two before and one of the involved nodes was removed.)  What would you like to do in that case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find the nodes in graph `G` with one outgoing edge using the `out_degree` method:

```
outdeg = G.out_degree()
to_remove = [n for n in outdeg if outdeg[n] == 1]
```

Removing is then:

```
G.remove_nodes_from(to_remove)
```

If you prefer to create a new graph instead of modifying the existing graph in place, create a subgraph:

```
to_keep = [n for n in outdeg if outdeg[n] != 1]
G.subgraph(to_keep)
```

Comment: after deleting those nodes, whether the out-degree will change?

Comment: In more recent versions of networkx, one may need the syntax like `[n for (n, deg) in outdeg if deg == 1]`